# How can I configure Hibernate to use SSL to talk to the DB server?

Tags: java, hibernate, configuration

I have an existing java webapp that uses Hibernate for it's persistence.  I've been told that I have to have to talk to the DB encrypted - so my first thought is to set it up to do the communication via SSL - and went through figured out how to set up Oracle to listen for JDBC over SSL -

`http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/pdf/wp-oracle-jdbc_thin_ssl_2007.pdf`

And wrote a quick test class to verify that it was setup and working (connecting via standard JDBC).  That left me with the issue of configuring Hibernate - unfortunately I don't see how hibernate supports it?

Comment: That link is dead, and I believe this is the updated version: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/wp-oracle-jdbc-thin-ssl-130128.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hibernate works with standard JDBC data sources, so there is no need for Hibernate-specific configuration.

Here's an quick example that should work when configuring Hibernate with Spring:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
    <property name="URL"><value><!-- JDBC URL that specifies SSL connection --></value></property>
    <!-- other relevant properties, like user and password -->
    <property name="connectionProperties>
        <value>
            oracle.net.ssl_cipher_suites: (ssl_rsa_export_with_rc4_40_md5, ssl_rsa_export_with_des40_cbc_sha)
            oracle.net.ssl_client_authentication: false
            oracle.net.ssl_version: 3.0
            oracle.net.encryption_client: REJECTED 
            oracle.net.crypto_checksum_client: REJECTED
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <!-- classes etc -->
</bean>
```

Comment: However I have to set some properties on the driver - using JDBC I can just do this :
 prop
        .setProperty("oracle.net.ssl_cipher_suites",
            "(ssl_rsa_export_with_rc4_40_md5, ssl_rsa_export_with_des40_cbc_sha)");
    prop.setProperty("oracle.net.ssl_client_authentication", "false");
    prop.setProperty("oracle.net.ssl_version", "3.0");
    prop.setProperty("oracle.net.encryption_client", "REJECTED");
    prop.setProperty("oracle.net.crypto_checksum_client", "REJECTED");

However how can I get thos properties associated with the driver through hibernate?

Comment: That depends how you are configuring Hibernate. I'll add an example that you can use with Spring in a moment.

Comment: If you are not using Spring, see Table 3.4 of the Hibernate docs: 
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional - although I haven't tested it, it seems that you can pass JDBC properties to Hibernate just by adding hibernate.connection.* properties.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://blablaba:8443/dbname?useSSL=true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.verifyServerCertificate">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.requireSSL">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">bablablab</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">clclclclc</property>
```

related links

http://www.razorsql.com/articles/mysql_ssl_jdbc.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html

http://www.javabeat.net/qna/164-hibernate-jdbc-and-connection-properties/

Comment: I tried your configuration but it does not give me any effect .

Answer (score 2):

Please add following property in Hibernate configuration file to enable SSL :

`<property name="hibernate.connection.verifyServerCertificate">false</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.useSSL">true</property>`

Comment: Is there anything new in this answer that the other answers haven't already said?

Comment: The others answer used: 


`<property name="hibernate.connection.requireSSL">true</property>`

But for my case it didn't worked. I have to use following to get it work :


`<property name="hibernate.connection.useSSL">true</property>`

Answer (score 1):

Should be handled by the driver but you may have to do some configuration.  [Oracle Docs](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/pdf/wp-oracle-jdbc_thin_ssl_2007.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I had the jdbcURL
`jdbc:postgresql://jdbcurl?sslmode=require&sslrootcert=location_to_cert1&sslcert=location_to_cert2&sslkey=location_to_cert3`.

All I had to do was to replace all the `&` with `&amp;`.

My new jdbcURL looks like
`jdbc:postgresql://jdbcurl?sslmode=require&amp;sslrootcert=location_to_cert1&amp;sslcert=location_to_cert2&amp;sslkey=location_to_cert3`