# Specifying certificates with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I was looking around for information on enabling SSL with Hibernate and I came across this([How can I configure Hibernate to use SSL to talk to the DB server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273403/how-can-i-configure-hibernate-to-use-ssl-to-talk-to-the-db-server)). I'm copy pasting the configuration mentioned in an answer, here.

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://blablaba:8443/dbname?useSSL=true</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.verifyServerCertificate">false</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.requireSSL">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">bablablab</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">clclclclc</property>
```

Which properties do I use to set the path to my certificate file, assuming that I'd like to set `verifyServerCertificate` to `True`?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you already have the certificate available, you need to either

add the path information on the command line:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=path_to_keystore_file
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=path_to_truststore_file
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password
```

Or you can set the values directly within the application:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","path_to_keystore_file");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","password");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","path_to_truststore_file");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","password");
```

Read [more from MySQL 5.1 documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html)