# (Tomcat) Java WAR connecting, via SSL, to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, ssl

**How do I tell tomcat to use a certain keystore for the applications it runs?**

I have a Java web application that needs to connect, via SSL, to a MySQL database.

I used a self-signed CA to sign all the certificates in use & 
have added the CA to a keystore (~/mystore.jks)

I have confirmed the proper configuration of MySQL for remote connection and tested the remote connection using the commandline. [Here is a link to my previous stackoverflow post that details the MySQL remote connection.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32377644/mysql-remote-connection-require-ssl)

I have seen many a blog stating how you can tell Java which keystore to use by setting the following options when executing your program on the commandline:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=path_to_keystore_file
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=path_to_truststore_file
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password
```

**But how do I tell tomcat to reference a keystore for the SSL connection it's application is seeking to attempt?**

*Side Note: I've also configured Tomcat to be SSL-only at the moment and it references a keystore for that too, but I've discovered/determined that **that** keystore is not referenced by the individual applications when negotiating their SSL connections.*

I would really appreciate some help here. This has proven much more cumbersome than I anticipated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide Tomcat with the ability to express commandline java options. It will provide those options to Java when it executes its webapps. [I found this very helpful post describing the process](http://www.yellowfinbi.com/YFForum-Connecting-to-MySQL-through-SSL-?thread=107524)

You need to add the following lines to **$CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh** (Unix)

[image: Java Options Specifying the keystore/truststore and passwords]

Then, restart Tomcat.

When Tomcat spins up, it does it through catalina.sh

It will provide those options to Java and you'll be good to go!

Answer (score -1):

There's a guide on how to configure tomcat-mysql connection over SSL in the Jira documentation.

http://bit.ly/1QnNAuK